# find word in text like chrome explorer, with javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angular8

I have information in array, and print it inside div with *ngFor. 
I want to add search box, the user write a word and when he click on search button the result seems like the search of chrome (when you press ctrl+F). It is possible? 
I need just the func..
Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll need to provide some code related to your application. We don't do black box support here. See the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To find information in an array, you can use `Array.prototype.find()`

Here an example :

```
const array = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
const found = array.find(element => element > 10);
```

As well, to find a string in javascript, you can use `string.search(searchvalue)`

Here an example :

```
var str = "Mr. Blue has a blue house";
var n = str.search("blue");
```